# Show text based on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Greetings all experts:

I have a login page and I am capturing not just user's username and password, I am also capturing whether the user who has visited us has voted or not.

I have put all of this into session variables:

If the user is successfully logged in, the user is taken to a menu page.

So far so good.

On the menu page, I have a link that says, Please click here to register.

I have been asked to show the link only if the user has not registered.

So, my initial approach is to have this bit on the `page_load()` event of menu page.

```
If session.Item("voted") = "1" Then 'User has voted Show the user the message that says, Thanks for your vote"

Else 'otherwise show the user the registration link

end if
```

Can someone please show me the syntax for this?

I am user vb.net but c# will do as well.

Thanks very, very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have a PlaceHolder control where you want the message or link to be and then try something like this in Page_Load

```
if (Session.Item["voted"] == "1")
{
    Label lblMessageToDisplay = new Label();
    lblMessageToDisplay.Text = "Thanks for your vote";
    placeHolder1.Controls.Add(lblMessageToDisplay);
}
else
{
    LinkButton registrationLink = new LinkButton();
    registrationLink.Text = "Please Register";
    registrationLink.PostBackUrl = "register.aspx";
    placeHolder1.Controls.Add(registrationLink);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your prompt response and for your assistance. Much appreciated. How do I mark it as the Answer?